# Unable to deploy jar on jetty

Tags: java, jar, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I almost go through every solution here on stack overflow but facing same problem. My jar file contains MANIFEST.MF file with correct location of main class. I want to deploy my application on Jetty and it is deploying by using ide. But whenever i try to run it from cmd like

> ```
> java -jar ../myApp.jar
> ```

face error which says

> ```
> Could not find or load main class
> ```

the file is present on the path it is showing in the error

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: package1.package2.package3.RunServers
```

Comment: post your MANIFEST.MF file content

Comment: @mallikarjun added

Comment: So your main class is in package1.package2.package3 and main calss is RunServers right?

Comment: @malikarjun yes exactly

Comment: Have you try to run the class instead of jar file by providing the dependent jars? For me the manifest and the class looks good. Does your class require any arguments to run?

Comment: what do you mean by providing dependent jars?

Comment: @ProgrammerBeta Seems you did not put the main class file into your jar file. Can you post the result of command `java -cp ../myApp.jar package1.package2.package3.RunServers`?

Comment: @AnarAmrastanov it says the same thing but when i open the jar using winrar the file is present on the path given in Manifest

Comment: Seems the only reason of that is the absence of the file in jar. Maybe you have some inaccuracy in package names or in file name.

Comment: @AnarAmrastanov if that was the problem it wiould be running from ide also.